C++ goto inside an OMP parallel loop
Is it correct to use goto inside omp parallel loop to move only inside it's body? (I know that goto is not the best style of writing code)
int read_arr[N]; // example array
int write_arr[N];  // example array
std::recursive_mutex m;

#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    LBL1:
    for (size_t k = 0; k < 10; k++)
    {
        bool flag = do_smth(k+i + read_arr[k]);
        if (flag)
        {
            m.lock();
            write_arr[i] = i + k;
            m.unlock();
        }
        else
        {
            m.lock();
            write_arr[i] = -1;
            m.unlock();
            goto LBL1;
        }
    }
}


In this case you can easily manipulate k to have the loop start back at 0 again.

k-loop is just an example, I want to know if goto is correct here

""I want to know if goto is correct here... goto is almost never correct/necessary.

Don't write code like this.

What happens if you replace goto with break?  A more correct usage of goto would be to jump to the end of the outer loop, from the inner most loop.

You can not jump out of a parallel loop. But since you're inside the loop body, it is fine. Style aside.

I this case I need goto ONLY for moving between different parts of parallel for loop body

I find that even when goto is the most elegant and readable way to solve a problem (which is almost never) I find it doesn't save me any time. I save a bit of writing, but then I have to defend it in the code review and to everyone who looks at the code until I tire of explaining it over and over and replace it with a clumsier conventional structure.

As @VictorEijkhout says, you can use any control flow you like (including goto, or even setjmp/longjmp, or throw/catch) to transfer control inside a single thread without that violating OpenMP rules.
As others point out, there's absolutely no need for a goto in this example (break is the normal way to leave a loop).
Not what you asked, but there's also no need to use any locking here. Only a single thread will have any given value of i, so there are no race conditions that you need to avoid.
